# Help me build a dagger focused character

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I wish to make an acrobatic, dagger using character. Lets call him for the sake of argument, Frederico.

Here are some qualities of Frederico:
Frederico is fast and agile. 40 feet speed would be nice. He should be able to get in and out of combat easily, having some defense against AOOs.

Frederico uses daggers exclusively. Might not be a Dagger, might be a Kuri or something, but dagger themed at the very least.

Frederico uses disposable daggers for ranged attack in case the target is too dangerous up-close. By disposable I mean he doesn't mind them being lost or sundered. Something like buying 20 daggers of +1 instead of a +3 (I am sure the math isn't right, I am guessing).

Frederico might invest his wealth into situational enchanted daggers, such as a specific undead weapon.

Frederico is a jack of all trades, master of none. He might be multiclassed to hell, no problem!

Frederico is versatile when fighting. He should be able to be effective vs 1 target

Frederico also has a variety of "toys". These are one-shot things like potions, alchemist fire & such that are kind of easy to get, whether by cheapness, commonness or the ability to create them. Perhaps a dip in Alchemist? This is to further strengthen his versatility.

Frederico, in case he is useless against a particular encounter, can assist another partymember, whether by using "toys" on him like buff/heal potions, cast spells if he has such an ability; or just provide flanking (I have read good things about Inquisitor's teamwork abilities) aid other, etc.

As far as skills and abilities are involved, I am not that keen on investing power in there but if necessity dictates (like needing high Craft and Int), so be it!

Frederico has medium survivability as far health, saves and AC are involved. Perhaps d8, good Fortitude and Reflex and some sort of a leather-like light armor. Mithral medium armor might be too expensive considering the investment in offensive abilities but why not? Buckler, maybe, something to be reflavoured as an arm guard on my part.

If it would help, watch Batman: Under the Red Hood. The character Red Hood, formerly known as Jason Todd, the second Robin. He returns from the dead with Batman training but with cold blood tactics.

I am looking for all 20 levels though we start at level 2 with this guy. d20pfsrd.com and official Paizo only.

If you need further specific details, ask away!

[image: Frederico]

P.S: More "toys", I just love this image:

[image]

Comment: What level(s) are you looking for? Are you using a point-buy(if so how much) and are you looking for a general pathfinder legal or pathfinder society legal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree that a two weapon rogue is the way to go. You would then want to take the [knife master archetype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/paizo---rogue-archetypes/knife-master) which will jack up your sneak attack damage to d8's instead of d6's with the dagger. Then take opportunist and other stuff designed to get you more attacks so you can proc that sneak attack more. For magic, invest in [fogcutting lenses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/fogcutting-lenses) because obscuring mist/fog cloud is everyone's favorite low cost way of denying rogues sneak attack.

Here's a sample 20 point buy Varisian knife master who uses starknives (proficiency courtesy Varisian Tattoo) for the x3 crit and 20' range and because they're cool red hood style toys. Using piranha strike you get-2/+4 with each, the agile starknife adds dex to damage, sneak attack's +3d8 with each one.

> **Stabby Stabberton**
>  Male Human (Varisian) Rogue (Knife
>   Master) 6
>  CG Medium Humanoid (human)
>  **Init** +6; **Senses**
>   Perception +10
>
> ---
>
> **Defense**
>
> ---
>
> **AC** 21,
>   touch 16, flat-footed 16 (+5 armor, +4 Dex, +1 deflection, +1
>   dodge)
>  **hp** 43 (6d8+12)
>  **Fort** +5, **Ref** +10,
>   **Will** +4; +1 trait bonus vs. charm and compulsion
>   **Defensive Abilities** blade sense +2, evasion, uncanny dodge
>
> ---
>
> **Offense**
>
> ---
>
> **Speed** 30 ft.
>  **Melee** +1
>   Agile Starknife +8 (1d4+5/x3) and
>     +1 Starknife
>   +8 (1d4+1/x3) or
>     Starknife +9 (1d4/x3), 20'
>  **Special Attacks**
>   sneak attack +3d8/+3d4
>
> ---
>
> **Statistics**
>
> ---
>
> **Str**
>   10, **Dex** 19, **Con** 14, **Int** 13, **Wis** 12,
>   **Cha** 10
>  **Base Atk** +4; **CMB** +4; **CMD** 20
>   **Feats** Combat Reflexes (5 AoO/round), Dodge, Piranha Strike
>   -2/+4, Quick Draw, Two-weapon Fighting, Weapon Finesse, Weapon Focus (Starknife)
>  **Traits** Reactionary, Varisian Tattoo
>   **Skills** Acrobatics +13, Appraise +8, Bluff +8, Climb +8, Disable
>   Device +12, Disguise +4, Escape Artist +8, Knowledge (dungeoneering)
>   +8, Knowledge (local) +8, Perception +10, Sense Motive +5, Sleight of Hand +8 (+11 to conceal a light blade), Stealth +13, Swim +8, Use
>   Magic Device +9
>  **Languages** Common, Goblin, Varisian
>   **SQ** hidden blade +3, rogue talents (combat trick, finesse rogue,
>   resiliency [1/day], weapon training)
>  **Combat Gear** Acid,
>   Alchemist's fire, Tanglefoot bag, Thunderstone; **Other Gear** +1
>   Mithral Shirt, +1 Agile Starknife, +1 Starknife, Dagger, Starknife,
>   Cloak of resistance +1, Ring of protection +1, 124 GP
>
> ---
>
> **Special Abilities**
>
> ---
>
> **Blade Sense +2 (Ex)** +2
>   dodge bonus to AC vs. attacks made against you with light blades
>   **Combat Reflexes (5 AoO/round)** Can make extra attacks of
>   opportunity/rd, and even when flat-footed.
>  **Evasion (Ex)** If
>   you succeed at a Reflex save for half damage, you take none
>   instead.
>  **Hidden Blade +3** +3 bonus on Slight of Hand checks
>   to conceal a light blade.
>  **Piranha Strike -2/+4** You can
>   subtract from your attack roll to add to your damage with light
>   weapons.
>  **Quick Draw** Draw weapon as a free action (or move
>   if hidden weapon). Throw at full rate of attacks.
>  **Resiliency
>   (1/day) (Ex)** When brought to 0 Hp or less, gain 6 temporary Hp for
>   1 min.
>  **Sneak Attack +3d8/+3d4** +3d8 damage with a
>   dagger-like weapon if you flank your target or your target is
>   flat-footed.
>  **Uncanny Dodge (Ex)** Retain Dex bonus to AC when
>   flat-footed.
>  **Varisian Tattoo**  +1 trait bonus on saving
>   throws against charm and compulsion effects.

Comment: @DavidOsborne Assuming that question about 7 feats is meant for me, this rogue took the rogue talents Finesse Rogue, Combat Trick, and Weapon Training, which gets you Weapon Finesse, any combat feat, and Weapon Focus respectively. Plus one for human plus three for levels.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your description, I think you are describing a [Rogue](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue).  If you are looking for an optimized version of the Rogue, you may want to read Rogue Eidolon's [excellent guide](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/community-creations/rogue-eidolon-s-lab/rogue-eidolon-s-guide-to-rogues).  Of the builds that are in that document, I would point you towards the 2 weapon rogue.

Answer (score 2):

Although it may surprise you, this type of character is not especially exotic or complex to craft.  Almost everything you've mentioned points simply toward the base class of **Rogue**.  With a nominal amount of feat and skill choices, you can represent your character very easily with this class.

A rogue generally has, or can be easily customized to have, the following traits:

- **"Average" d8 health** (up from d6 in 3.5)
- **"Jack of all trades" property**: They are the middle-road class in terms of several aspects of combat ability.  They are the best at most skills in general, although they generalize in a great number of avenues.
- **Specializes in daggers**: While not literally forced to specialize, daggers are one of their most effective weapons within their base proficiencies, and are great for getting the most out of their Sneak Attack, one of their primary methods of dealing damage.  Daggers can be used in melee or ranged combat equally at will with no penalty to one over the other.
- **Fast**: Rogues do not have an innate speed boost over the typical 30 ft speed, although they don't have any penalties either, often wearing light armor.  It is possible to increase your speed beyond your natural levels.  They also have great agility (reflex saves and special abilities that utilize it exceptionally) and use dexterity well.

Comment: if dual wield, why not use stronger weapons than a dagger? perhaps a dagger prestige would be more proper? If one is indeed forced to specialize in daggers, at least get some power out of it.

Comment: @Discipol One of the great things about daggers is that they are very versatile, and that this is an advantage in itself outside of any special powers or abilities.  The fact that they can be used in both melee and ranged combat equally without any need to switch weapons is, alone, extremely powerful.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this may be a bit more of an unusual build for a dagger-themed character, but may I suggest a Monk. To be precise a monk wielding Lungchuan tamo. The reason for this suggested weapon is that it's a set of daggers that are nearly identical stat-wise(crits on 20 vs 19-20) as ordinary daggers, however a monk can flurry with them(melee or thrown).

The reason for a monk over a rogue is that when flurrying, he gets a higher BAB as well as being able to apply the full strength bonus with both hands. In addition, a monk gets higher base speed, as well as a number of bonuses(such as better CMB, Slow Fall and a really good bonus to acrobatics for the purposes of jumping).

A monk build(with a 'dagger' focus) would be better able to deal with single or mulitples in open combat(more attacks with better to hit), less so in ambush(no sneak attack)

Comment: Monks aren't automatically proficient with the lungchuan tamo, although they can flurry with them.  This would be a great use for the Weapon Adept archetype, too.  +1 for an alternative option.

Comment: I'm curious about alternatives too, thanks for not taking the obvious road.

Comment: I realize that a monk doesn't start with proficiency with the Lunchuan tamo, however, since a monk does get a few bonus feats(as well as an effective TWF in Flurry), for a Monk to spend a feat for a proficiency isn't quite as costly as otherwise.